# Python function from another def function

Tags: python, python-3.x

This question may have been asked for fundamentals of Python, unfortunately, I spent an hour looking for the answer, but couldn't find it. So I am hoping for someone's input. I am used to writing Class where I can give `self` and get the variable into the `def function` from another function. How do I capture that variable without writing a `Class function`? Is there a way? Thanks!

```
import pandas as pd 

file_Name = 'test.xlsx'

def read_file():
    df = pd.read_excel(file_Name)
    return df
read_file() 

def clean_data():
    text_data = df['some_column_name'].str.replace(';',',') # How to get df from read_file() function?
    return text_data
clean_data()
```

Comment: You don't need arguments here. Just call it in your `clean_data` method. (e.g `df = read_file()` )

Comment: To pass variables to a function's scope, use the function's arguments

Comment: Do you mean something like this?: `read_file(x)`, where `x` is variable to be captured.

Comment: @sharp see my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're overthinking it:

```
df = read_file()
clean_data()  # Uses the global variable df capturing the return value of read_file
```

Or course, `clean_data` *should* take an argument rather than using a global variable.

```
def clean_data(f):
    text_data = f['some_column_name'].str.replace(';', ',')
    return text_data

f = read_file()
clean_data(f)
```

Answer (score 1):

Call the first function and save the returned dataframe in a variable `df`. Then call the second function (`clean_data`) and pass this `df` inside it **as argument**.

Use this:

```
import pandas as pd 

file_Name = 'test.xlsx'
import pandas as pd 

def read_file():
    df = pd.read_excel(file_Name)
    return df
df = read_file() 

def clean_data(df):
    text_data = df['some_column_name'].str.replace(';', ',')
    return text_data

clean_data()
```

Answer (score 0):

In general... you can use global variables. But with how your method is set up, you should just do

```
df = read_file()
```

inside of your clean_data() method. Then use df from there. Notice df is just the local name for the result of calling read_file(), you can call it anything.